# Perform an authenticated keystone.js / GraphQL API query

Tags: node.js, authentication, graphql, keystonejs

I am new to Keystone.js and GraphQL. So far I have been able to successfully execute the following API queries (taken from this [page](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/intro-to-graphql)) via a POST request:

```
const SIGNIN = `mutation signin($identity: String, $secret: String) {
  authenticate: authenticateUserWithPassword(email: $identity, password: $secret) {
    item {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}`;

// Returns id and name of authenticated user
```

and

```
const GET_ALL_POSTS = `query GetPosts {
  allPosts {
    name
    id
  }
}`;

// Returns id and name of all posts (if no access controls)
```

If I set [access controls](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/access-control) for the list `Post` I get an access error from the second query as expected, but I can't work how to then perform an authenticated query for `allPosts`, e.g. I want:

- To (programatically) authenticate a user by their email and password
- If successful, run a query for `allPosts` and return the results

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to first submit the query below, to authenticate your user and generate an access token:

```
query: `mutation ($identity: String, $secret: String) {
  authenticate: authenticateUserWithPassword(email: $identity, password: $secret) {
    token
  }
}`
```

Subsequent queries are then authenticated by adding the provided token to your headers of your request with:

```
'Authorization: Bearer <token>'.
```

Further information [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/authentication#graphql).

More generally, [the GraphQL playground](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/intro-to-graphql#execution) is well worth a look for anyone getting into keystonejs and new to GraphQL.