# Session / token verification in custom KeystoneJS endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, session, bearer-token, keystonejs

I am successfully authenticating user requests to my KeystoneJS API with the approach outlined [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/authentication).

However I need to add a custom express endpoint to my application, which should only accessible to users with a valid token in their request header ([see this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077526/perform-an-authenticated-keystone-js-graphql-api-query/63112432#63112432)).

I've been digging through the Keystone docs regarding sessions and middleware, but it's not my area of expertise and I can't work out how request tokens are being validated.

How can I validate the token in the authorisation header of a `GET` request to my custom endpoint? Appreciate this may relate to express and session management rather than Keystone specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a standard setup, the following can be added to `configureExpress` (see [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/custom-server#you-may-not-need-a-custom-server)) to apply Keystone session middleware to a custom express endpoint:

```
app.use('/myEndpoint', keystone._sessionManager.getSessionMiddleware({ keystone }));
```

Then:

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost:4200'];
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.post('/myEndpoint', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    // User is authorised
    res.send(req.user);
  } else {
    res.status(401).send()
  }
});
```

Notes / gotchas:

- Your `POST` request must include a GraphQL query to authenticate your user against
- CORS options must be properly configured
- A `sessionStore` must also be provided - see [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/keystone/#sessionstore)